# 'No such file or directory' yet it exists?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, jupyter

I am relatively new to Stack Overflow and Python so please excuse me. 
I ran into an issue with Jupyter trying to open my notebook.  Specifically, this error is:

```
Unreadable Notebook: /home/vagrant/Notebook 1.ipynb NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: u\'{\\n "cells": [\\n {\\n "cell_type": "...',)
```

I am trying to recover this file as it is pretty crucial!  I discovered there is hidden folder accessible by the terminal called .ipynb_checkpoints and after listing all contents in this folder I am presented with this.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 656710 Dec  6 17:25 Notebook 1-checkpoint.ipynb

-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  26332 Oct 19 21:47 Lab08-checkpoint.ipynb

-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant     72 Nov 17 16:35 Untitled-checkpoint.ipynb
```

The top one Notebook 1-checkpoint.ipynb is the file I would like to recover.  Can anyone please help me with this?

When I try to do this:

```
cp Notebook 1-checkpoint.ipynb /home/vagrant/Desktop/
```

I am presented with this:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘Notebook’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘1-checkpoint.ipynb’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to use quotes or other escaping -- otherwise, the spaces mean that your single argument is split, so `cp` thinks you're telling it to copy *two* files, one named `40126684_Notebook` and the other named `1-checkpoint.ipynb`.

Comment: BTW, questions about command-line usage rather than software development are generally a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se], not StackOverflow. An issue using `cp` *certainly* doesn't have anything to do with Python or Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks very much @CharlesDuffy.  You've saved my semester.  I will take your advice going forward.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your command should be `cp 40126684_Notebook\ 1-checkpoint.ipynb /home/vagrant/Desktop/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the escape charachter '\' before spaces as stated by @theBrainyGeek 
or quotes:
`cp "40126684_Notebook 1-checkpoint.ipynb" /home/vagrant/Desktop/`